# Lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: table overflow

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I am new to Lua and Nginx. I have a Lua file that does the authentication of any request hitting NGINX.

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
local cjson = require("cjson")
local iam = ffi.load("/gateway/auth/main/libiam.so")

ffi.cdef([[
  typedef long long GoInt64;
  typedef GoInt64 GoInt;
  typedef struct { const char *p; GoInt n; } GoString;
  extern GoInt VerifyToken(GoString p0);
  extern GoInt64 VerifyApiKey(GoString p0);
]]);

local accessToken = ""
local apiKey = ""
local result = 0
local typeString = ffi.typeof("GoString")
local unauthorizedJson={}

if ngx.var.http_Authorization and string.len(ngx.var.http_Authorization) > 0 then
      if ngx.var.http_Authorization:sub(1, #"Bearer") == "Bearer" then 
        ngx.log(ngx.STDERR, 'Verifying bearer token.')
        accessToken = string.sub(ngx.var.http_Authorization,8)
        local  accessTokenString= typeString(accessToken, string.len(accessToken))
        result = iam.VerifyToken(accessTokenString)
      else 
       
        apiKey = ngx.var.http_Authorization
        local  apiKeyString= typeString(apiKey, string.len(apiKey))
        result = iam.VerifyApiKey(apiKeyString)
      end
      if tonumber(result)~=0 then
        -- we are ok here and proceed to route to upstream
        if string.len(apiKey) > 0 then 
          ngx.req.set_header("abc", result)
        end
      else

        return ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)  
      end

else

  return ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)  
end
```

I am seeing the following error intermittently

```
Lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: table overflow
```

at this line

```
ffi.cdef([[
```

I am using openresty. Can any one please tell me what could be the issue here?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/openresty-en/c/I5Vax1jDIsM

Answer (score 0):

I stand corrected. Both ffi[[ and ffi([[  are acceptable